# docker-compose gives ERROR: No such service: bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

I'm new to Docker and trying to refresh my db with commands

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml run --rm bundle exec web rake db:refresh
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml run --rm bundle exec web rake db:test:refresh
```

but I get the next error

**ERROR: No such service: bundle**

```sh
gem list bundler
```

shows the next

```sh
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.1.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

My ruby version is ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-darwin19]

Maybe someone can help me, I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle` is not a defined service in your docker-compose-dev.yml file.

I suspect the command should be something like

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml run --rm web bundle exec rake db:refresh`

Note the position of `web`.